# Uploading multiple images does not get added to FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data

I have method which detects files (in this case images):

```
detectFiles(event) {
this.formData = new FormData();
this.urls = [];
this.files = event.target.files;
if (this.files) {
  for (const file of this.files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.urls.push(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}}
```

the files I've got are saved in `this.files` and on submit button I do this:

```
  submitForm(value: any) {
if (value) {
  this.formData.append('Title', value.title);
  this.formData.append('Date', value.date);

  for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    const chosenFileName = this.files[i].name;
    const chosenFile = this.files[i];
    this.formData.append('file', chosenFileName, chosenFile);
  }

  this.authService.uploadFile(this.formData)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {

      },
      (error) => {
      }
    );
}}
```

here, I add values from input and then go through loop to add all the files I've got. 
In the example, I added to pictures, however they did not appear in the request. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was a dummy one:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    const chosenFileName = this.files[i].name;debugger;
    const chosenFile = this.files[i];
    this.formData.append('file', chosenFile); // <----- changed this line
  }
```